# About a notation in Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis"

Tags: notation, limsup-and-liminf

On page 14.

> Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of extended-real functions on a set $X$. Then $\sup\limits_nf_n$ and $\limsup\limits_n f_n$ are the functions defined on $X$ by
>   $$
> \left(\sup_nf_n\right)(x)=\sup_n(f_n(x)),
> $$
>   .....

How to understand these two $n$s of $\sup\limits_n(f_n(x))$? May it be
$$
\sup \{f_n(x),f_{n+1}(x), \cdots\}?
$$
But in Theorem 1.14 on the same page, there is another notation: $\sup\limits_{n\geq 1}f_n$, this theorem says

> If $f_n:X\to [-\infty, +\infty]$ is measurable, for $n=1,2,3,\ldots,$ and 
>   $$
> g=\sup_{n\geq 1} f_n,~~~~h=\limsup_{n\to \infty} f_n,
> $$
>   then $g$ and $h$ are measurable.

In the proof, there is a $g^{-1}((\alpha, \infty]=\cup_{n=1}^\infty f_n^{-1}((\alpha, \infty])$. From here I guess that $\left(\sup\limits_{n\geq 1}f_n\right)(x)=\sup\{f_1(x), f_2(x), \cdots\}$, is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subscript of $\sup$ is meant to denote the variable for which the supremum is taken, and when it isn't clear from context, where that variable ranges. That is:
\begin{align}
\sup_n(f_n(x))&:=\sup\{f_n(x): n\in\Bbb N\}\quad\text{we 'guess' the range from context}\\
\sup_{n\geq k}(f_n(x))&:=\sup\{f_n(x): n\geq k\}\quad\text{we are explicitly given the range}
\end{align}